# Passing on variable to invoke-item

Tags: powershell

Looking for a solution. I have simple script that will browse to specific directory on network pc's.

However I'm not sure how to pass on $compname variable to  invoke-item.
I'm running PS v2.0. With current script I'm getting error: Invoke-Item : Cannot find path '\\C$\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Notes\Data' because it does not exist.

```
$dskbox = New-Object system.windows.Forms.TextBox
$dskbox.Width = 134
$dskbox.Height = 20
$dskbox.location = new-object system.drawing.point(24,41)
$dskbox.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10,style=Bold"
$Title.controls.Add($dskbox)
$compname = $dskbox.Text


$Open = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Button
$Open.BackColor = "#23b14d"
$Open.Text = "Open"
$Open.ForeColor = "#ffffff"
$Open.Width = 163
$Open.Height = 51
$Open.location = new-object system.drawing.point(6,77)
$Open.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10,style=Bold"
$Title.controls.Add($Open)


$Open.Add_Click({


ii "\\$compname\C$\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Notes\Data"

}) 

[void]$Title.ShowDialog()
$Title.Dispose()
```

Comment: There seems to be a typo. You assign `$dskbox.Text` to `$compname`, then refer to `$companame` (notice the extra *a*)

Comment: Thanks Mathias, Well spotted. Fixed this error, but still getting same error message. '\\\C$\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Notes\Data' because it does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `$compname` when creating the textbox, which is obviously going to be empty at that point in time. You need to move it into the scriptblock:

```
$Open.Add_Click({
    $compname = $dskbox.Text
    ii "\\$compname\C$\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Notes\Data"
})
```

Or you could just get rid of that variable entirely: `ii "\\$($dskbox.Text)\C$\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Notes\Data"`

Answer (score 0):

You can associate your `$Open.add_Click($Open_OnClick)` to a scriptblock and start `invoke-item` inside the scriptblock.

```
$dskbox = New-Object system.windows.Forms.TextBox
$dskbox.Width = 134
$dskbox.Height = 20
$dskbox.location = new-object system.drawing.point(24,41)
$dskbox.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10,style=Bold"
$Title.controls.Add($dskbox)
$compname = $dskbox.Text


$Open = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Button
$Open.BackColor = "#23b14d"
$Open.Text = "Open"
$Open.ForeColor = "#ffffff"
$Open.Width = 163
$Open.Height = 51
$Open.location = new-object system.drawing.point(6,77)
$Open.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10,style=Bold"
$Open.add_Click($Open_OnClick)
$Title.controls.Add($Open)

$Open_OnClick= 
{
   ii "\\$compname\C$\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Notes\Data"
}

[void]$Title.ShowDialog()
$Title.Dispose()
```